# Get windows serial for XP, Vista and Seven

Tags: windows, vb.net, windows-7, windows-vista, license-key

I'm retrieving Windows XP license key with this function but it does not work for Vista and Seven. How can I get the license key at both of these Windows versions?

```
Public Function sGetXPKey() As String
    Dim result As String = String.Empty

    Dim RegKey As RegistryKey = _
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", False)
    Dim bytDPID() As Byte = RegKey.GetValue("DigitalProductID")
    Dim bytKey(14) As Byte
    Array.Copy(bytDPID, 52, bytKey, 0, 15)
    Dim strChar As String = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
    Dim strKey As String = ""

    For j As Integer = 0 To 24
        Dim nCur As Short = 0
        For i As Integer = 14 To 0 Step -1
            nCur = CShort(nCur * 256 Xor bytKey(i))
            bytKey(i) = CByte(Int(nCur / 24))
            nCur = CShort(nCur Mod 24)
        Next
        strKey = strChar.Substring(nCur, 1) & strKey
    Next

    For i As Integer = 4 To 1 Step -1
        strKey = strKey.Insert(i * 5, "-")
    Next

    Return strKey
End Function
```

Comment: Why do you need to get the serial key?

Comment: I'm using the serial's md5 hash to produce a license key for my program.

Comment: Why not just use the hash of the encrypted value? or is it the read of the key that fails on Vista+ ?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: bytDPID is empty on Windows 7 x64 :). I've looked at the registry and there was also a DigitalProductID4 key. But not sure to use it.

Comment: But if you're only after something unique to do an MD5 hash of, just use that as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the registry I'd suggest that you should use WMI. Specifically the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28VS.85%29.aspx). As can be seen on that page there is a property called `SerialNumber`.

[This](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/151.html) page contains a complete sample (with explanations) for how to do it.

Comment: I'm getting error when trying to define ManagementObjectSearcher, Management.ManagementObjectCollection and Management.ManagementObject.

Comment: @HasanGursoy: I think you probably need to add a reference to `System.Management` (In case you haven't done that before, on the `Project` menu, choose `Add Reference` and then scroll down to the one you need).

Comment: Hmm yes you're right. I though Imports System.Management is enough.

Comment: @HasanGursoy: That's enough for the common parts of the framework, but a few of them you need to add manually (Management and DirectoryServices are the only ones I can think of right now that I've used that needed that).